# Irregular grid shape

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is it possible to create an irregular grid shape?
I attached a picture which clearly explains my intentions.

[image: Picture of irregular grid shape]

Comment: Please, why is it such a bad question? What is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

You could use ColumnSpan to merge those cells.

If you want them to look as if they're not part of the grid, then set their background color to the window background color.

Comment: No, i need to add another component to that space. And when i merge it, it will remain active which is bad when i use databinding.